# ROS2 nodes don't "step" when Gazebo simulation is stepped forward

Tags: ros, ros2, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a simulated robotic system running ROS2 Foxy, and we've noticed that the nodes relying on the Gazebo ROS interface remain frozen when we step the simulation forward by N iterations. Things work as expected when the simulation is unpaused, but when we pause the simulation and try to advance the simulation manually, we can see the Gazebo simulation time progresses but none of the ROS interfaces do anything.

For instance, we can look at the `/clock` topic, see that new timestamps are getting published while the simulation is unpaused, pause the simulation and no new messages are published, step the simulation in Gazebo forward by 10 seconds, and unpause the simulation and we see a sudden jump in the time being published to the new time.

We quickly tried this same experiment in ROS1 Melodic and *did not* have the same issue.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have any tips on getting ROS2 nodes to continue to function when a gazebo_ros simulation is stepped forward?

([Associated issue](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/1324))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389593/ros2-nodes-don%27t-%22step%22-when-gazebo-simulation-is-stepped-forward/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a bit more digging, I think the issues we have been experiencing are due to [the publisher "Throttler" checking the realTime clock instead of the simTime clock](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/c1793e17069b9785568956f7cb10b9fb646abed1/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_init.cpp#L260-L262)

```
void GazeboRosInitPrivate::PublishSimTime(const gazebo::common::UpdateInfo & _info)
{
  if (!throttler_.IsReady(_info.realTime)) {  // <-- HERE
    return;
  }

  rosgraph_msgs::msg::Clock clock;
  clock.clock = gazebo_ros::Convert<builtin_interfaces::msg::Time>(_info.simTime);
  clock_pub_->publish(clock);
```

For whatever reason, the `realTime` is not updated when stepping the simulation. As a result, the `gazebo_ros` interface never publishes clock updates when the simulation is paused and is being stepped. All other nodes relying on the `/clock` topic unsurprisingly stop working as expected.

In [gazebo_ros_pkgs#1325](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/1325), I suggest a simple 'fix' of simply changing:

`if (!throttler_.IsReady(_info.realTime)) {`

to:

`if (!throttler_.IsReady(_info.simTime)) {`

This does the trick for our purposes. However, it looks like it causes a few build tests to fail. I will try to investigate these to see if they are a concern, and will update this answer if anything comes up.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0